# XML Schema with enumeration

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I am using XJC to create from XML Schema a Jaxb annotated class.
With

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeClass.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(cardJob, writer);
String resultString = writer.getBuffer().toString();
```

I create an xml output string - This works perfect. What I want to achieve is, adding an enum to this class like

```
Jan (1, "January"),
Feb (2, "February"),

...
```

by creating an entry in the xml schema and getting in the end 
an output like
<.January><./January>.
Maybe wrong but something like an xml element from an enum entry name.

Help would be pretty great, cause I dont get any solution :(

Comment: If you use XSD enumerated types Java enums should be created automatically...

Comment: yeah thats true but i need an output like <.January><./January>.

Comment: The following may help, just replace `String` with your enum:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/represent-string-values-as-element.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can build your own ContentHandler
`org.xml.sax.ContentHandler`

handle the enums and put them into buffer before endDocument

`marshaller.marshal(obj, new yourContentHandler());`